# Switching themes with Polymer <core-style>

Tags: polymer

I'm unsure of the most idiomatic way to use Polymer's `<core-style>` to switch user-selected CSS themes. Right now I'm doing this:

```
    <template if="{{ theme == 'theme-grey'}}">
        <core-style ref="theme-grey"></core-style>
    </template>
    <template if="{{ theme == 'theme-blue'}}">
        <core-style ref="theme-blue"></core-style>
    </template>
    <template if="{{ theme == 'theme-red'}}">
        <core-style ref="theme-red"></core-style>
    </template>
```

Where the producers are brought in via imports. This works ok but it seems a little wordy. I had imagined doing something like this:

(doesn't work)

```
    <core-style id="theme" ref="theme-red"></core-style>
    ...
    themeChanged: function(oval, nval) {
        this.$.theme.ref = nval;
    }
```

I guess that doesn't work because you can't set both ref and id, and looking over the `<core-style>` source I'm not sure that ref is intended to be changed dynamically.  So is the template block the correct approach? Thanks.

Edit: this doesn't seem to work either:

```
    <core-style ref="{{theme}}"></core-style>
```